# Deriving the bivariate polynomial basis functions

Tags: polynomials, surfaces, curves, algebraic-curves

Is there a means of computing the bivariate polynomial basis functions for an $n^{th}$-order polynomial from the associated $n^{th}$-order univariate polynomial basis functions? E.g. How is $\{1, x, y, x^2, xy, y^2\}$ computed from $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and $\{1, y, y^2\}$. I have done a bit of searching, but have not found a definite answer to this. My initial guess was that it would involve the outer product, but this produces an $x^2y^2$ term.

Comment: Would it be $\sum_{r+s=n}x^ry^s$ or do you need something else?

Comment: Your expression suffices! Thank you. I was just looking for a compact way to write this in my thesis.

Comment: Interesting... what's the approach in this "thesis"? [Just curious]

Comment: Fitting higher-order polynomial curves/surfaces to liquid-gas interfaces to compute local curvature for the purpose of computing surface tension force.